# flashcards a4paper: Frames on back- don't match those on frontpage

Tags: positioning, flashcards

Within flashcards environments on a4paper: The frames of the flashcards on the frontsite do not exactly fit (size and location) to the corresponding frames on the backsite of the page. I tested my files with kile on linux and texnicenter on windows and on different printers without. I use PDFLaTeX for pdf production.

mycards.cfg:

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}[1996/12/01]
\ProvidesFile{mycards.cfg}
\newcommand{\cardpaper}{a4paper}
\newcommand{\cardpapermode}{portrait}
\newcommand{\cardrows}{4}
\newcommand{\cardcolumns}{2}
\setlength{\cardheight}{70mm}
\setlength{\cardwidth}{100mm}
\setlength{\topoffset}{2mm} 
\setlength{\oddoffset}{5mm}
\setlength{\evenoffset}{5mm}
\endinput
```

flashcard sample:

```
\documentclass[mycards,frame]{flashcards}
\usepackage{ngerman}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % this is needed for umlauts
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel} % this is needed for umlauts
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}    % this is needed for correct output of umlauts in pdf
\usepackage{enumitem}


\begin{document}

\cardfrontfoot{Untersuchungstechniken}

\begin{flashcard}{Inspektion}
{
  \begin{enumerate}\setlength{\itemsep}{-5pt}  
  \item äußere Verletzungsfolgen
  \item konstitutionelle Veränderungen
  \item Hautveränderungen
  \item Achsabweichungen
  \item Haltung
  \item Gangbild
  \item Spontanmotorik
  \end{enumerate}
 }
\end{flashcard}

\begin{flashcard}{Inspektion Gehen}
{
  \begin{enumerate}\setlength{\itemsep}{-5pt}  
  \item Schrittlänge
  \item Wendeschrittzahl (alterabhängig, Anzahl der Einzelschritte für 360$^\circ$ normal bis 4)
  \item Mitschwingen der Arme
  \end{enumerate}
 }
\end{flashcard}

\begin{flashcard}{ Evozierte Potentiale Definition }
{
\begin{flushleft}
     Potentialunterschiede im Elektroenzephalogramm (EEG), welche durch eine Reizung eines Sinnesorgans oder peripheren Nervs ausgelöst werden. 
     \\ \quad
     \\ Im weiteren Sinn können alle gezielt ausgelösten elektrischen Phänomene im EEG als evozierte Potentiale verstanden werden.
\end{flushleft}
 }
\end{flashcard}

\begin{flashcard}{ Evozierte Potentiale Eigenschaften }
{
    \begin{enumerate}\setlength{\itemsep}{-5pt}        
      \item Evoziertes Potential: 1-15 $\mu$V
      \item Spontanes EEG Potential: 50-100 $\mu$V
      \item EEG wird als stochastisches Störsignal, das \textbf{von dem Reiz unabhängig} ist und dessen Mittelwert Null ist, betrachtet, während das interessierende evozierte Potential zeitlich an den Reiz gekoppelt ist
      \item Lichtblitze Potential: 50 Reize
      \item frühen akustische Hirnstammpotentiale: 1000 bis 2000 Reize
      \item Form der Welle
      \item Wellenhöhe (Amplitude)
      \item Laufzeit (Latenz)
    \end{enumerate}
 }
\end{flashcard}

\begin{flashcard}{Lhermitte-Zeichen }
{
  \begin{enumerate}\setlength{\itemsep}{-5pt}  
  \item Kopf  passiv nach vorne beugen
  \item positives Lhermitte-Zeichen: Missempfindungen (Parästhesien, "elektrisierendes Gefühl") in den Extremitäten oder am Rumpf an. Meistens geht die Missempfindung vom Nacken aus. 
  \item positives Lhermitte-Zeichen entsteht durch die Dehnung der Hirnhäute durch Beugung der Wirbelsäule im Halsbereich. 
  \item Vorkommen: entzündlichen Veränderungen und Tumoren des Rückenmarks, ausgeprägten Spondylarthrosen und bei der Encephalomyelitis disseminata (Multiple Sklerose) vor. 
  \end{enumerate}
 }
\end{flashcard}

\begin{flashcard}{Nackensteifigkeit}
{
\begin{flushleft}
Passives Kopf beugen führt zu \textbf{positiven Dehnungszeichen} bei \textbf{meningitischer Reizung}; (uLZ umgekehrtes Las\'egue-Zeichen) Zeichen:
\end{flushleft}
    \begin{itemize}[align=left,labelwidth=\widthof{Brudzinski:},leftmargin=\labelwidth+\labelsep]\setlength{\itemsep}{-5pt}
      \item[Las\'egue:]  Anheben gestrecktes Bein $\rightarrow$ Dehnungsschmerz
      \item[Las\'egue:]  Anheben gestrecktes Bein $\rightarrow$ einseitiger Dehnungsschmerz $\rightarrow$ radikuläre Reizung
      \item[uLZ:] Bauchlage Anheben des gestreckten Beines $\rightarrow$ Dehnungsschmerz $\rightarrow$ radikuläre Reizung
      \item[Kernig:] passiv gestrecktes angehobenes Bein wird gebeugt
      \item[Kernig:] Schmerzangabe, wenn gebeugtes Bein gestreckt wird
      \item[Brudzinski:] Passive Kopfbeugung führt zu anziehen der Knie
    \end{itemize}
 }
\end{flashcard}




\end{document}
```

How to fit size and location of frames on backpage exactly to frames on frontpage?

Comment: you seem to need the `calc`-package, aswell.

Comment: The difference for me is tiny and may be due to not having A4 paper to print on (I have to shrink to fit the printable area).

Answer (score 2):

I realized it with an extra line

```
\documentclass[avery5371,grid]{flashcards}

\renewcommand{\cardpaper}{a4paper} %<-- THIS IS THE ANSWER
\renewcommand{\cardrows}{5}


\cardfrontstyle[\large\slshape]{headings}
\cardbackstyle{plain} %centreert beide
%\cardbackstyle{empty} %centreert enkel de voorkant


\begin{document}
\cardfrontstyle{headings}
\cardfrontfoot{Functional Analysis}

\begin{flashcard}{Dense Subset}
       A subset $S$ of a normed space $B$ is called \emph{dense}
       in $B$ if {\rm cl} $S$ = $B$.
     \end{flashcard}

\begin{flashcard}{Dit is de vraag}
dit is het antwoord 
\end{flashcard}


\end{document}
```